# Consul not registering services when it comes up

Tags: consul

In my configurations, service definitions are kept in `/etc/consul.d/server`.

Consul is started with following command:

```
consul agent -config-dir /etc/consul.d/server
```

When consul is started, none of the service is registered. However, same services can be registered using web API with same definition files.

What is the issue with multiple service definitions as they are not getting registered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have multiple files? If so -> make sure they all end in .json.

Also When loading configuration, Consul loads the configuration from files and directories in lexical order. For example, configuration file basic_config.json will be processed before extra_config.json. Configuration specified later will be merged into configuration specified earlier. In most cases, "merge" means that the later version will override the earlier. In some cases, such as event handlers, merging appends the handlers to the existing configuration. The exact merging behavior is specified for each option in the docs.

https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options.html

Otherwise try to put all your service definitions into one json file.

using the services key in your configuration file. (not the plural S)

```
{
  "services": [
    {
      "id": "red0",
      "name": "redis",
      "address": "127.0.0.1",
      "port": 6000,
    },
    {
      "id": "red1",
      "name": "redis",
      "address": "127.0.0.1",
      "port": 7000,
    },
  ]
}
```